# Can I create a user-specific hosts file to complement /etc/hosts?

Tags: non-root-user, hosts

Is it possible to add a list of hosts that are only specific to a certain user? Perhaps a user-specific hosts file?

This mechanism should also complement the entries in the `/etc/hosts` file.

Comment: well, you might instead run own nameservers, and have the user use different nameservers per user-specific resolv.conf - except creating user-specific resolv.conf appears to be exactly as difficult as making user-specific /etc/hosts.

Comment: If the server is remote, you might try the ~/.ssh/config file: [this post](http://superuser.com/questions/291778/unable-to-use-scp-with-a-bash-alias).

Answer (score 186):

The functionality you are looking for is implemented in glibc. You can define a custom hosts file by setting the `HOSTALIASES` environment variable. The names in this file will be picked up by `gethostbyname` (see [documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/gethostbyname.3.html)).

Example (tested on Ubuntu 13.10):

```
$ echo 'g www.google.com' >> ~/.hosts
$ export HOSTALIASES=~/.hosts
$ wget g -O /dev/null
```

Some limitations:

- `HOSTALIASES` only works for applications using `getaddrinfo(3)` or `gethostbyname(3)`
- For *setuid*/*setgid*/*setcap* applications, libc sanitizes the environment, which means that the `HOSTALIASES` setting is lost. *ping* is setuid root or is given the `net_raw` capability upon execution (because it needs to listen for ICMP packets), so `HOSTALIASES` will not work with `ping` unless you're already root before you call `ping`.

Comment: Note that it doesn't work if you're using `nscd` and is limited to hostnames without a dot.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on CentOS 6

Comment: Late to the party, but this is the inverse of what is desired, isn't it?

I think OP is looking for a similar solution to adding host-resolving entries to /etc/hosts, but one that can be done in userland without escalated privileges.

(i.e. `127.0.0.1 somedomain.com`)

Comment: I don't remember then but these days ping isn't a suid binary in Linux; it uses capabilities. If you run *`getcap /usr/sbin/ping`* you might see something like: *`/usr/bin/ping = cap_net_admin,cap_net_raw+p`*.  And technically it's that it needs to open a raw socket rather than ICMP (but I suppose you could argue that's just semantics).

Comment: Despite the man says "the alias file pointed to by HOSTALIASES will first be searched for name" the priority is random and if run this wget example a dozen of times it goes wrong.

Comment: Does not work on MacOS :(

Comment: `HOSTALIASES` only works for names **without any dots** -- see [`__res_context_search()`](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/4fc321dc58b2/resolv/res_query.c#L375-L380)

Answer (score 51):

Beside the `LD_PRELOAD` tricks. A simple alternative that may work on a few systems would be to binary-edit a copy of the system library that handles hostname resolution to replace `/etc/hosts` with a path of your own.

For instance, on Linux:

If you're not using `nscd`, copy `libnss_files.so` to some location of your own like:

```
mkdir -p -- ~/lib &&
cp /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files.so.2 ~/lib
```

<sub>(the shared library may be located elsewhere, e.g. `/lib/libnss_files.so.2`)</sub>

Now, binary-edit the copy to replace `/etc/hosts` in there to something the same length like `/tmp/hosts`.

```
perl -pi -e 's:/etc/hosts:/tmp/hosts:g' ~/lib/libnss_files.so.2
```

Edit `/tmp/hosts` to add the entry you want. And use

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/lib
```

for `nss_files` to look in `/tmp/hosts` instead of `/etc/hosts`.

Instead of `/tmp/hosts`, you could also make it `/dev/fd//3` (here using two slashes so that the length of `/dev/fd//3` is the same as that of `/etc/hosts`), and do

```
exec 3< ~/hosts
```

For instance which would allow different commands to use different `hosts` files.

If `nscd` is installed and running, you can bypass it by doing the same trick, but this time for `libc.so.6` and replace the path to the nscd socket (something like `/var/run/nscd/socket`) with some nonexistent path.

Comment: +1 for audacity, -1 for the shock value

Comment: +1 for binary patching, -1 for security implications

Comment: @ParthianShot, what security implications?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Changing `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to point to a directory owned by the user means any other process run by the user can use that directory to co-opt any new processes spawned by replacing libraries. And updates to `libnss_files.so` through the package manager (including security updates) won't be reflected in the patched version. Modifying `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is generally a bad thing to recommend for other reasons, but it's also unwise because of those issues.

Comment: @ParthianShot, your point about missing updates is a fair point. However, for your other point, if a rogue software is running in your name, it having write access to an area in $LD_LIBRARY_PATH would be the least of your worries as it's already got write access to a lot worse and more reliable areas like your .bash*, crontab, .forward, and all configuration files by all the software you use (where it can for instance set LD_{PRELOAD,LIBRARY_PATH} but would typically do a lot worse)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Any idea why it would work with `LD_PRELOAD` but not with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`? Here's what I am running on shell: https://paste.ee/r/KE1Hl

Comment: @BerkantIpek, it's likely a `libnss_files.so.2` file `getent` is looking for, not `libnss_files.so`. Check with `LD_DEBUG=libs  getent hosts`

Answer (score 39):

Private mountspaces created with the `unshare` command can be used to provide 
a private /etc/hosts file to a shell process and any subsequent child processes started from that shell.

```
# Start by creating your custom /etc/hosts file
[user] cd ~
[user] cat >my_hosts <<EOF
127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
127.0.0.1 news.bbc.co.uk
EOF

[user] sudo unshare --mount
# We're now running as root in a private mountspace. 
# Any filesystem mounts performed in this private mountspace
# are private to this shell process and its children

# Use a bind mount to install our custom hosts file over /etc/hosts
[root] mount my_hosts /etc/hosts --bind

[root] cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
127.0.0.1 news.bbc.co.uk

[root] exec su - appuser

[appuser] # Run your app here that needs a custom /etc/hosts file

[appuser] ping news.bbc.co.uk
PING news.bbc.co.uk (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.062 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.026 ms
^C
--- news.bbc.co.uk ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 999ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.026/0.044/0.062/0.018 ms
```

Comment: Wait.  I thought mount just mounted filesystems onto directories (mount points).  I didn't know that a file could be mounted onto another file.  Does that really work?  (I am asking that seriously.  That isn't sarcasm.)

Comment: Yep, it works, you can mount a file over another file with --bind.

Comment: Just as a note to those curious: this is to do with namespaces; there are the syscalls *`unshare(2)`* and *`clone(2)`* that is part of the magic here. See also *`namespaces(7)`* and *`user_namespaces(7)`*.

Comment: This is really cool!

Comment: While it can be really helpful, user namespaces are also a big security risks as numerous exploits in the last years have shown. This is not used above (ie you need sudo rights) but should be mentioned. Debian has disabled them on default. One other thing that should also be considered is that to use `unshare` you have to execute/fork another process. Thus it is not completely trivial to implant it in a shell script for automation. One way is to pass the whole code into `sh -c` as argument of `unshare` as explained here: https://piware.de/2012/12/running-a-script-with-unshared-mount-namespace/

Answer (score 8):

I faced the same need, so I tried libnss-userhosts, but it fails at multithreaded applications. Therefore I have written [libnss-homehosts](https://github.com/bAndie91/libnss_homehosts). It's very new and tested only by me. You may give a chance for it!
It supports some options in /etc/host.conf, multiple alias names, and reverse resolving (address to name).

Comment: This seems like a good idea to pitch to the libnss maintainers and/or to distribution maintainers. But before that happens, users without root themselves will not be able to use it. Still, +1

Comment: @bandie your tool works perfect on my Linux. Do you know any similar solution for MacOS?

Comment: @Nicolai, unfortunately no. does not MacOS have libnss? if so, libnss-homehost can be ported to.

Answer (score 6):

One solution is to have each user in a separate `chroot`, so they can each have a separate `/etc/hosts` to themselves.

Comment: This could be an answer, but as stated with little explanation it is more suited as a comment

Comment: Well... yeah, it's doable. Although chrooting is a pretty heavy-duty solution for this kind of thing. And brings with it its own set of issues.

Answer (score 4):

Placing the following in `~/.bashrc` is working for me in bash. It converts the hostname in the command into an address based on entries in `~/.hosts`. If `~/.hosts` doesn't exist or if the hostname can't be found in `~/.hosts`, the command executes as normal. This should work with the original flags of the relevant functions and regarless of where the hostname is placed relative to the flags, e.g. `ping -i 0.5 host1 -c 3`, works. The `~/.hosts` file takes preference over any other location for finding hostnames, so if there are any dupicate hostnames, the address in `~/.hosts` will be used.

```
$ cat ~/.bashrc 
function resolve {
        hostfile=~/.hosts
        if [[ -f "$hostfile" ]]; then
                for arg in $(seq 1 $#); do
                        if [[ "${!arg:0:1}" != "-" ]]; then
                                ip=$(sed -n -e "/^\s*\(\#.*\|\)$/d" -e "/\<${!arg}\>/{s;^\s*\(\S*\)\s*.*$;\1;p;q}" "$hostfile")
                                if [[ -n "$ip" ]]; then
                                        command "${FUNCNAME[1]}" "${@:1:$(($arg-1))}" "$ip" "${@:$(($arg+1)):$#}"
                                        return
                                fi
                        fi
                done
        fi
        command "${FUNCNAME[1]}" "$@"
}

function ping {
        resolve "$@"
}

function traceroute {
        resolve "$@"
}
```

An example of `~/.hosts` is given below. It follows the same format as `/etc/hosts`. Comments and whitespace are handled correctly.

```
$ cat ~/.hosts 
# addresses and hostnames
stackexchange.com se

192.168.0.1 host1 # this is host1's address
login-node.inst.ac.uk login
```

Comment: Can git or wget use this "resolve"? Or just your function who use function "resolve"?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this would help you, but I came here looking for a way to add saved "hosts" somewhere that was easily accessible to only my user.

I basically needed to be able to ssh into certain boxes on our work network, which only has one entry point.

What I did was add aliases to my `.bashrc` file.

For example, if you added:

```
alias jrfbox='ssh jason@192.168.6.6'
```

at the bottom of your `~/.bashrc` (`~` is your home directory). Then after you logout and login again, you can type `jrfbox`, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and it will connect.

Comment: If you're interesting specifically in the SSH case, you should see `man ssh_config`.

Comment: You do not have to log out and back in again to reload `~/.bashrc`, simply do `source ~/.bashrc`.

Comment: @user991710 Or for that matter *`. ~/.bashrc`*

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to override dns resolution in google chrome in windows, mac and linux without root/admin access. All we need to do is to start google chrome process with a switch and supply the required DNS entries there.

May be you can append the switch to the shortcut of google chrome in windows or softlink of google chrome in linux so that it varies for each user.

https://devopslife.io/resolve-dns-locally-using-google-chrome/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to run the answer by [frielp](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/242830/542208) in a script

```
#!/bin/sh                                                                                                                                                                                     
set -e
# call this file through unshare in a way that keeps normal stdin, $0, and CLI args                                                                                                           
sudo unshare -uim sh -c "$(tail -n +7 $0)" "$0" "$@"
exit $?

# unshared program starts here                                                                                                                                                                
set -e
echo "mounting my_hosts file as /etc/hosts"
sudo mount my_hosts /etc/hosts --bind
su - khalfani-tmp bash -c "ping new.host.com"                                                                                                                                                                      
echo "done"
```