# How can I override the /etc/hosts file at user level?

Tags: linux, dns, hosts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I create a user-specific hosts file to complement /etc/hosts?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10438/can-i-create-a-user-specific-hosts-file-to-complement-etc-hosts)

In short: I would like to know if it is possible to get a `~/hosts` file that could override the `/etc/hosts` file, since I don't have any privileged access.

A machine I am working on does seem to be properly configured with a correct DNS server. When I try to ping usual machine **name** I am working with, it fails. But when I try to ping them by **IP address** it works as expected.

I want to avoid changing any scripts and other *musuculary memorized handcrafted commmand line* ™ that I made because of a single unproperly configured machine. I contacted sys admin, but they have other fish to fry.

How can I implement that?

Comment: Similar to http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10438/can-i-create-a-user-specific-hosts-file-to-complement-etc-hosts. Based on the info, it looks like a DNS configuration problem

Comment: Nothing *standard* like that, I'm afraid. But do check @dartonw's link, especially the first (accepted) answer with LD_PRELOAD.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Beside the LD_PRELOAD tricks. A simple alternative if you're not using `nscd` is to copy `libnss_files.so` to some location of your own like:

```
mkdir -p -- ~/lib &&
cp /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files.so.2 ~/lib
```

Binary-edit the copy to replace `/etc/hosts` in there to something the same length like `/tmp/hosts`.

```
perl -pi -e 's:/etc/hosts:/tmp/hosts:g' ~/lib/libnss_files.so.2
```

Edit `/tmp/hosts` to add the entry you want. And use

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/lib
```

for `nss_files` to look in `/tmp/hosts` instead of `/etc/hosts`.

Instead of `/tmp/hosts`, you could also make it `/dev/fd//3`, and do

```
exec 3< ~/hosts
```

For instance which would allow different commands to use different `hosts` files.

```
$ cat hosts
1.2.3.4 asdasd
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/lib getent hosts asdasd 3< ~/hosts
1.2.3.4         asdasd
```

If `nscd` is installed and running, you can bypass it by doing the same trick, but this time for `libc.so.6` and replace the path to the nscd socket (something like `/var/run/nscd/socket`) with some nonexistent path.

Comment: Might want to add this answer to the previous (duplicate) question, if you haven't already.

Comment: What a HACK! ;-) I didn't tested it. But it deserves an accepted answer.

Comment: What does "replace the path to the nscd socket (something like /var/run/nscd/socket) with some nonexistent path" mean?

Comment: I tested it and while it works to define new host entries or re-define existing ones, it does not work to remove /etc/hosts entries, i.e. /etc/hosts domain blocking still works. Which is good in a way. Good hack though. :)