# How to edit /etc/hosts without sudo?

Tags: ssh, permissions, sudo, hostname, hosts

I have a machine that I can only access using SSH.

I was messing with the hostnames, and now it says:

```
ssh: unable to resolve hostname
```

I know how to fix it in `/etc/hosts`.

Problem is, I need `sudo` to fix them because my normal account doesn't have permissions.

What's the best way to fix the hosts?

Comment: Instead of editing `/etc/hosts`, maybe http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10438/can-i-create-a-user-specific-hosts-file-to-complement-etc-hosts would help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need sudo to fix that, try `pkexec`,

```
pkexec nano /etc/hosts
pkexec nano /etc/hostname
```

After running `pkexec nano /etc/hosts`, add your new hostname in the line that starts with `127.0.1.1` like below,

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   your-hostname
```

And also don't forget to add your hostname inside `/etc/hostname` file after running `pkexec nano /etc/hostname` command,

```
your-hostname
```

Restart your PC. Now it works.

Comment: I'm a little confused. What exactly does `pkexec` do? Also when I ran it on the hosts file, it showed up with a blank doc. When I saved, did I overwrite what was there?

Comment: `pkexec allows an authorized user to execute PROGRAM as another user. If
       username is not specified, then the program will be executed as the
       administrative super user, root.
`

Comment: So it's like a backup/fake sudo? Awesome!

Comment: And, I'm not sure why it showed blank, but it seems to have worked -- now I'm trying to fix the actual hosts problem

Comment: Yes, try to fix that. You said "I know how to fix it in /etc/hosts and /etc/hostname"

Comment: I thought I did, but apparently I didn't =)

Comment: Anyway, pkexec needs to authenticate the user to execute the command before running it

Comment: bash: pkexec: command not found

Answer (score 4):

You need sudo or root privileges to edit the `/etc/hosts` file in your local host. If you don't, there is no way of editing this file.

Then you must add an entry to `/etc/hosts` so that your local host can resolve properly the hostname of the remote host.

This is the format of the lines in `/etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1   localhost.localdomain   localhost
10.10.2.9   remotehost.labs         remotehost
```