# How to change the host file after login

Tags: networking, configuration, non-root-user

Was wondering whether in a Nix environment I can change the content of the host file, mainly to prevent one or two site being accessed from that particular user, and only for his account (not with admin privileges).

I though about the rc.local file, but I'm not sure this could work.

Is there any other local config file I can use?

Thanks
Andrea

Answer (score 2):

`HOSTALIASES` might meet your requirements.

The question is related to:
[Can I create a user-specific hosts file to complement /etc/hosts?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10438/can-i-create-a-user-specific-hosts-file-to-complement-etc-hosts)

Here is a resource where `HOSTALIASES` is explained:
http://blog.tremily.us/posts/HOSTALIASES/