# Why I mount --bind --make-private /etc/hosts in new namespace, modification of this file with vim in old namespace will also affect the new ns?

Tags: filesystems, mount, namespace, container

I want to create a new namespace with a different `/etc/hosts`, so I tried to use `mount --bind` with unshare to create it as referenced in this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/242830/271204

```bsh
# Create temp hosts
export TEMP_HOSTS=$(mktemp XXXXXXX.hosts)
trap "{ rm -f $TEMP_HOSTS; }" EXIT
cat /etc/hosts > $TEMP_HOSTS

# Create new ns
unshare -m bash
mount --make-private "$TEMP_HOSTS" /etc/hosts --bind
```

Then I got a new shell (denoted as Shell2), and wrote something to it. It's ok and `/etc/hosts` is still in mount after append or edit.

```
(Shell2) # cat /proc/self/mountinfo | grep /etc/hosts
218 189 8:1 /tmp/Z3flEXS.hosts /etc/hosts rw,relatime - ext4 /dev/sda1 rw,errors=remount-ro
(Shell2) # echo '127.0.0.1 aaaa' >> /etc/hosts
(Shell2) # cat /proc/self/mountinfo | grep /etc/hosts
218 189 8:1 /tmp/Z3flEXS.hosts /etc/hosts rw,relatime - ext4 /dev/sda1 rw,errors=remount-ro
```

When I start a new terminal window or create or new ssh session, I get a shell with old namespace of the system and denote it as Shell1.

The /etc/hosts under Shell1 is still the old version as expect because the mount is `--make-private`. But when I modify the /etc/hosts under Shell1 with `vim, /etc/hosts under Shell2 is also changed and the mount is disappeared.

```
# Append "127.0.0.1 aaaaa" with vim, or you can use vim interactively.
(Shell1) # vim -c "$ s/$/\r127.0.0.1 aaaaa/" -c "wq" /etc/hosts
(Shell1) # md5sum /etc/hosts
1580e29f05e6af70012afe37ce08cb5a  /etc/hosts
```

```
(Shell2) # cat /proc/self/mountinfo | grep /etc/hosts
* Nothing here
(Shell2) # md5sum /etc/hosts
1580e29f05e6af70012afe37ce08cb5a  /etc/hosts
```

But in the step of modifying /etc/hosts in shell1, `/etc/hosts` in new namespace will not be affected when I use `echo '127.0.0.1 aaaa' >> /etc/hosts` instead of using `vim` to edit and **save**.

So my question is why I modified file with `vim` in old namespace, the file in the new namespace is also been affected? Why the behavior is different when using shell redirection? Can I change `unshare` or `mount` options to avoid the change caused by vim in old namespace?

Comment: Thanks a lot! At when the problem occurred, I used vim to edit the file. Modification of file with shell redirection indeed can not reproduce it. I have updated the description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `vim` is not editing the file in place -- when saving the file, vim creates a temporary file in the same directory and then renames it to the original.

You'll probably get the same effect with `cp /etc/hosts{,~}; mv /etc/hosts{~,}` (or with `sed -i`, which does the same thing as `vim`); renaming a file to another is like unlinking the old dir entry and then creating another one in its place (but in a single atomical step).

The unlinking part is obliterating any mount from another namespace.

And this is intended behaviour -- see the calls to `detach_mounts` in [`fs/namei.c`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.3/source/fs/namei.c#L4288) from `vfs_{unlink,rename,rmdir}()`. Only a mount in the *same* namespace will cause them to fail with `EBUSY`.

That feels a bit sketchy, but without this, any process could mount over a file or directory in a private namespace as a way to prevent it from ever being removed ----- which may turn into a denial of service attack [1]

The same puzzling behaviour happens when you mount over files under `/proc/PID/` -- the mount just disappears when process `PID` exits, without being explicitly unmounted.

---

[1] This is actually the rationale from the [commit](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=8ed936b5671b) which changed the behaviour in 2013, also mentioned in the [mount_namespaces(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/mount_namespaces.7.html) manpage:

> Previously (before Linux 3.18), attempting to unlink, rename,
> or remove a file or directory that was a mount point in
> another mount namespace would result in the error `EBUSY`.  That
> behavior had technical problems of enforcement (e.g., for NFS)
> and permitted denial-of-service attacks against more
> privileged users.  (i.e., preventing individual files from
> being updated by bind mounting on top of them).

Comment: That's it. I used `strace` with `vim` and found it rename file to name suffix with `~` and write to `/etc/hosts` then unlink the old file. According to https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/mount_namespaces.7.html it would never results `EBUSY` when unlink mountpoint at other namespace in recent kernel versions.